# Application of Rouche's theorem on $x^4-6x+3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm being asked to find the number of zeros given $|z|<1$ and $1<|z|<2$. So here are my inequalities but I'm not quite sure how to find the number of zeros though based on these inequalities.

$|6z-(6z-z^4-3)|=|z^4+3|<|z^4|+3\leq4<6|z|=6$ for the first one and for the second one we have
$|z^4-(z^4-6z+3)|=|6z-3|\leq6|z|+3=15<16=|z^4|$

Are these applied the right way and how would I be able to tell the number of zeros in a disc?

Answer (score 0):

Your inequalities are right except for minor mistakes ($<$ instead of $\leq$ is what i spotted) but you need to tell what you are doing not just write them down and don't do anything with it.
In a little more detail:

Let $$\begin{array}[t]{l} f(z) = z^4-6z+3 \\ g(z) = 6z\\ h(z) = -z^4\end{array}$$

For $|z| = 1$ we have $|f(z)+g(z)| = |z^4+3| \leq |z^4|+3 = 4 < 6 = |6z| = |g(z)|$.
Hence, using Rouché's theorem, we get that $f$ and $g$ have the same amount of zeros in $B(0,1)$. Since $g$ has exactly one zero in $B(0,1)$, $f$ also has exactly one zero there.

Now, for $|z| = 2$ we have $|f(z)+h(z)| = |-6z+3| \leq |6z|+3 = 15 < 16 = |z^4| = |h(z)|$. So we get that $f$ and $h$ have the same amount of zeros in $B(0,2)$. Since $h$ has $4$ zeros there, the same is true for $f$. But since $f$ already has $1$ zero in $\overline{B(0,1)}$ there are exactly $3$ zeros left to be in $\{z\in\mathbb C~\vert~ 1<|z|<2\}$.